# How regex match a statement with optional end part?

Tags: python, regex

A statement such as:

```
[string1...] string2 in english/chinese (string3...)
```

string3 is in `()` and is optional.

I write a regex pattern in python:

```
(\[(?P<string1>.*)\])\s*(?P<string2>.*)\s(\((?P<string3>.*)\))?
```

But as `*` is greedy match and string3 will be parsed within string2.

I use lookahead match string3 such as:

```
(\[(?P<string1>.*)\])\s*(?P<string2>.*(?=\())\s*((?P<string3>.*)\))?
```

But is also no match.

How should I get the three match part, and the last part is optional within `()`?

Comment: @anubhava no other possible inputs, all are in this pattern.

Comment: Does input have literal `?` in the end, as shown in question?

Comment: @anubhava sorry, the last `?` indicate string3 is optional, I will remove it in the plain text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex based on negation pattern with anchor `$`:

```
\[(?P<string1>[^\]]*)\]\s*(?P<string2>[^()]*)(?:\s+\((?P<string3>.*)\))?$
```

Here we're using 2 negation sub-patterns:

```
[^\]]*  # matches 0 or more of any char that 
[^()]*  # matches 0 or more of any char that is not ( and )
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jP2aI8/1)

Comment: I've no idea Jan why downvote appeared within seconds of posting. Looks like a trigger happy downvoter didn't even bother to read the answer.

Comment: Some compensation from me then (happy upvoter, that is ;-)

Comment: Thanks,  `[^\]]*` can match all but except `]`, I thought this way but not known how to implement it

Comment: Yes negation based regex is the way to make it work rather than using `.*`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ?

```
^(?P<string1>\[[^]]+\])       # anchor it to the start
(?P<string2>[^(\n]+)          # everything not a (
(?:\((?P<string3>[^)]+)\))?$  # sth. in (), optional
```

With `multiline` and `verbose` mode, see <kbd>[a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pF9nM0/1)</kbd>.
In `Python`:

```
import re
string = "[string1...] string2 in english/chinese (string3...)"
rx = re.compile("""
    ^(?P<string1>\[[^]]+\])       # anchor it to the start
    (?P<string2>[^(\n]+)          # everything not a (
    (?:\((?P<string3>[^)]+)\))?$  # sth. in (), optional
""", re.MULTILINE|re.VERBOSE)
matches = rx.findall(string)
```

Comment: Hi, in string2, why exclude '\n' for newline?

Comment: @TankyWoo: because of the demo (regex101), you do not need it in your real example.

Answer (score 2):

In your regex I see `\(` just before `string 3`, which means that string 3 is enclosed within parenthesis. In this case you can match `string 2` upto no left parenthesis is found like this.

**Regex:** `(\[(?P<string1>.*?)\])\s*(?P<string2>[^\(]*)\s*(\((?P<string3>.*)\))?`

Note the `[^\(]` in group `string2`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJ8iR1/1)**